# Using statvfs to get total and free filesystem size

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, posix, system-calls

I want to use the return values from statvfs to get the total and free filesystem size.

```c
unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* Filesystem block size */
unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* Fragment size */
fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* Size of fs in f_frsize units */
fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* Number of free blocks */
...
```

Source: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/statvfs.3.html

So to get the total filesystem size, it seems like I want `f_blocks * f_frsize`, since the comment for `f_blocks` says that it's the size "in `f_frsize` units". However, `f_bfree` is the number of free blocks. So for free filesystem size, I have to use `f_bsize`? Or `f_frsize` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments of blocks seems to be a filesystem feature in some legacy filesystems (googling suggests UFS and JFS have a use for it).

The fragment size seems to indicate the minimum value a fragment is allowed to be and should be between 1 and `f_bsize`.

On filesystems that do not support it, this value should equal `f_bsize` (or be zero, see below) since further fragmentation of the block wouldn't be supported.

If you check the `coreutils` source code (on redhat based systems at least) you can see how GNU handle this in `df`. Given GNU is *supposed* to handle all kinds of POSIX semantics with various flavours of UNIX not just Linux, it should offer a fairly robust suggestion on how to resolve this.

In `lib/fsusage.c`

```
120       if (statvfs (file, &vfsd) < 0)
121         return -1;
122 
123       /* f_frsize isn't guaranteed to be supported.  */
124       fsp->fsu_blocksize = (vfsd.f_frsize
125                             ? PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_frsize)
126                             : PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_bsize));
127 
128       fsp->fsu_blocks = PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_blocks);
129       fsp->fsu_bfree = PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_bfree);
130       fsp->fsu_bavail = PROPAGATE_TOP_BIT (vfsd.f_bavail);
131       fsp->fsu_bavail_top_bit_set = EXTRACT_TOP_BIT (vfsd.f_bavail) != 0;
132       fsp->fsu_files = PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_files);
133       fsp->fsu_ffree = PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_ffree);
134       return 0;
```

In their code, they are copying the POSIX `statvfs` struct into a struct of their own making, the important part however is in lines `124-126` which shows what they are doing: using the `f_frsize` if its not zero  otherwise using `f_bsize`.

My suggestion is to just copy their method as `df` has seen extremely wide distribution in the wild and through time. One would hope that someone would have indicated it reports the wrong values by now if it was incorrect.

You should also be aware more modern filesystems have a rather nebulous concept of filesystem usage. `btrfs` springs to mind which due to reflink copies, quotas and snapshots doesn't give an exact absolute value anymore.
You probably want to treat this as more as an exception rather than the rule at this stage but something you might want to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks. It was driving me mad that I was getting 85,000 GiB free.

Answer (score 1):

Google is your best friend. Result of ["difference vs f_frsize and f_bsize"](https://www.unix.com/hp-ux/254087-about-block-size-fragment-size.html) 
=>" if you have block size 8KB and trying to write a 1KB file to the block, as result you waste 7KB of the block space. But recently I noticed about Fragments of File Block. In same case if you have File Block 8KB and Fragment size 1KB - you can save your block space, because 1KB file will fill only 1 fragment. Other 7 fragments will use for other files."
The answer is for your question is: use the f_bsize.